# If $\int_{T} e^{int} d\mu(t)=0, n=1,2,3,\dots$, then either $\mu=0$ or the support of $\mu$ is all of $T$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure on $T$ s.t.
$$\int_{T} e^{int} d\mu(t)=0,   n=1,2,3,\dots$$
Prove that then either $\mu=0$ or the support of $\mu$ is all of $T$.

Comment: What is $T$? ${}$

Comment: @WillM. $T=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of general Hardy spaces theory and a sketch of the proof would be like this (we assume $\mu$, not identical zero as there is nothing to prove then - there are other approaches and i sketched the one by Helson in another answer but this is easier here )

1: The property $\int_{T} e^{int} d\mu(t)=0,   n=1,2,3,\dots$ represents the fact that $\mu$ is an analytic measure (if you want, one can take the definition of analytic measure like that)

2: It follows that $2\pi f(re^{i\theta})=\int_{T} P(r, \theta-t) d\mu(t)$ is analytic in the open unit disc, where $P(r, \theta-t)=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos (\theta-t)+r^2}$ is the usual Poisson kernel, because it is equal to the Cauchy-Stieltjes transform of $\mu$, $2\pi F(z)=\int_{T}\frac{e^{it} d\mu(t)}{e^{it}-z}$ since in general $f(z)=F(z)-F(\frac{1}{\bar z})$ by a simple computation, but the analytic property of $\mu$ means precisely that $F$ cancels outside the unit disc so $F(\frac{1}{\bar z})$ which is conjugate analytic is just zero for $\mu$ as given (hence the name analytic measure btw)

3: But then since $||P||=1, P(re^{i\theta}) > 0$, it follows that $\sup_{0<r<1}|f(re^{i\theta})|_1 \le ||\mu|| < \infty$, so there is a non-tangetial finite limit $f(e^{i\theta}$ a.e for which $f(z)$ is the Poisson transform, and then by the unicity of that we get $f(e^{it})dt=\mu(t)$, so $\mu$ is absolutely continuos and its support is precisley the support of $f$ so one needs to show that $f$ doesn't vanish on a set of non-zero measure

4; $\log |f(e^{it})|$ is integrable on the unit circle (this follows from Jensen's theorem and Fatou lemma but essentially it is due to the fact that the integrals of $\log |f(re^{it})|$ can only increase with $r$ for analytic $f$ inside the unit disc, but not decrease, so non-integrability on the boundary can happen only if the value is $+\infty$ but not $-\infty$, and that doesn't happen in this case - so we actually need less than the full result here since $f=0$ on a set of measure non-zero implies the integral of $\log |f|$ is $-\infty$)

Hence we are done!